# Are these two schematics the same?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, schematics

I am attempting a diy project and I am completely new to electronics so please bear with me. I found a schematic online which I want to create a pcb from. I know the very basics about pcbs and schematics in general.

The original schematic I found uses three 8-pin ICs but the way the schematic was drawn has each IC's 8 pins split up into two separate-looking parts for easy understanding.

I tried to recreate the same schematic but with each actual 8-pin IC as one solid component. This is so I can create a PCB easier (layout out etc).

Could you kindly look at both the original and my redrawn one and see if I have done it correctly and it is exactly the same circuit before I order the board? I would really appreciate it.

**Original:**
[image]
**Re-drawn one:**
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58361/discussion-on-question-by-bruno-are-these-two-schematics-the-same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pointed out some of the problems in the below diagram- there may be more, I just ran out of patience and my coffee arrived:

[image]

The dot on C2 means you didn't line up the wire with the end. It will still be okay but it looks ugly. I didn't flag it but C2 and C3 do not have polarity. The symbol should be different. U1 1&2 are shorted. V- on the op-amps is wrong on all 3 (but in two different ways). The pots and the 6 connections to each pair are completely wrong. R9 is the wrong value. The output jack J3 has left and right channels swapped, and so does the input jack (not marked).

I agree with the comment that not breaking the op-amp into proper symbols as in the original makes it harder to follow. I have yelled at people for this kind of thing. That is a style issue, but it's more worrisome that you have missed a lot of details.

Consider looking at the netlist that Orcad generates (in human readable form)-- you should be able to see each individual net and verify which pin of which part is connected to each net.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question. This is my first ever attempt at anything electronics, so it is clear I may have bitten more than I can chew. I have so much to learn. Thanks! Hope the coffee was delicious.